# Get Data from all objects of a queryset in django

Tags: django

I have three models `Order`, `OrderEntries` and `Product`

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_entries = models.ManyToManyField(OrderEntries, blank=True)
    ...

class OrderEntries(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

Now, I have to get history of purchased products. As I can get all previous orders placed by a user like this

```
queryset = Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, client=self.request.client)
```

But how I can get list of products from all those orders?

Comment: can you share the product model code

Comment: @BelhadjerSamir I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a related_name on the ForeignKey field as follows:

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
```

You could then access the products in your template, for example:

```
{% for order in orders %}
  {% for order_entry in order.order_entries %}
     {% for product in order_entry.products.all %}
        {{ product }}
```

Please note: it isn't necessary to set related_name. If you don't set it, you can use BLA_set where BLA is the name of the field e.g.:

```
{% for product in order_entry.product_set.all %}
```

Comment: Please note, where I have used 'orders', here that is based on the assumption that you are not using 'queryset' for your variable that gets assigned to the filtered Order objects. If you are, you should use, {% for order in queryset %}. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help :

```
product=[]
for e in queryset:
   for ord in e['order_entries']:
       for pr in ord['product'] :
             product.append(pr)
```